# Are .shp files coordinates in a certain direction?

Tags: shapefile, spatial-database

I'm working on a project where I'm importing a .shp file into SQL Server.  I'm using the Catfood.dll and I'm wondering if each point in the polygon are sequential (going in the same direction)?

Comment: It is difficult to discern what you might mean by "going in the same direction."  Whatever it is, you will find all your questions about shapefiles answered in the [technical specification](http://www.esri.com/library/whitepapers/pdfs/shapefile.pdf).

Comment: By direction, are you referring to the ordering of the vertices?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In shapefiles, the winding of the polygons is consistent and the vertices are sequential so that the right-hand side of the line (when following the vertices) is inside the polygon and the left-hand side is outside.  The consequence of this is that an exterior ring has vertices wound clockwise and and interior ring (or hole) is wound anti-clockwise.

Non-ESRI implementations of the shapefile specification do not always follow all the rules (including the one about polygons should not be self-intersecting) and are a frequent source of invalid geometry when moving between systems.

Comment: How can I tell if a .shp is a "Non-ESRI" implementation?

Comment: There's no way just from the the file AFAIK.  If the shapefile came from software that isn't produced by ESRI then it would be 'non-ESRI'.  That's not to say it is necessarily bad, just that it often works that way.  The Shapefile format is very old and much abused.  Don't worry about it unless you have bad geometry - and even then, a lot of systems have tools which can attempt to fix it.

Comment: doesn't the fix hurt the precision though?

Comment: It depends on how the fix has been implemented and what it is fixing.  For instance, you may get a multipolygon with two parts instead of a single self-intersecting polygon but all the vertices left with their exact same vertices... so not necessarily.